# Selenium CDP Connection error on Fetch : Chrome DevTools

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium4, chrome-devtools-protocol

Getting errors in Fetch continue request implementation

Chrome version : 18.0.5993 Java : 17

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-continueRequest

Errors

> org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevToolsException:
> {"id":2440,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"Invalid state for
> continueInterceptedRequest"},"sessionId":"CD483E6DB97D096120A659EDA82D6A29"}
> org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevToolsException:
> {"id":2441,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"Invalid state for
> continueInterceptedRequest"},"sessionId":"CD483E6DB97D096120A659EDA82D6A29"}

Code

> Optional devToolsOpt =
> ((HasDevTools)driver).maybeGetDevTools();
>
> ```
>     if (devToolsOpt.isPresent()) {
>         DevTools devTools = devToolsOpt.get();
>         devTools.createSessionIfThereIsNotOne();
>         devTools.send(Fetch.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
>         devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
>         devTools.addListener(Fetch.requestPaused(), req -> {
>         List<HeaderEntry> customHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
>
>         // adding current request headers + additional headers to customHeaders
>
>   
>          devTools.send(Fetch.continueRequest(req.getRequestId(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(),
>             Optional.empty(), Optional.of(customHeaders), Optional.empty()));
>            
>         });
>     }
> ```